# GCP Cloud Function minimum instances with serverless.yml

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, serverless

Is there any way to set minimum instances for google cloud function in serverless.yml file? There is property maxInstances, that works, but I can't find how to set minimum instances number.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, at the present moment, it is not possible to set the minimum number of 'hot' instances of cloud functions to avoid cold starts for your application and reduce application latency.

In the future it may be possible - see [Overview: Cloud Functions (2nd gen)](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/2nd-gen/overview), and particularly how to [use minimum instances](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/min-instances).

Answer (score 0):

Following works for me, using `frameworkVersion: '3'`

```
functions:
  first:
    handler: http
    events:
      - http: path
    minInstances: 1
```